# How to migrate an old MySQL database into a new WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am about to 'inherit' an older website built in PHP and it uses a custom mySQL database. The intention is to setup a whole new site in the same domain (different folder) and then port the data over from the old site to the new.

But is there a tool or script available that will help me identify the old database fields so I can 'transpose' old to new?

**EDIT**: It could be that MySQL Workbench is the answer?

Comment: Define *"a custom mySQL database"*. Plus, if you have PHPmyadmin or anything else similar that lets you export your DB schema/table information, you can save it as an `.sql` file then import it into your new DB.

Comment: By 'custom' I mean it is not a database created from a CMS like WP or Joomla. So it's table structure will be entirely different in the old database to the new.

Comment: I tend to think that SQL is SQL; that shouldn't change. Server folder structure however, now that's a different animal altogether. If there are any references to folders or http calls etc. inside SQL, then that's going to be a different ball of twine altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the phpMyAdmin of your older database click export, you will get a file. Go to the phpMyAdmin of your new database and import the file that you downloaded before, and you will get the same data that you had in your old database into your new one.

I think this solution solves your problem.
Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: If they were the same structure I could do this but the structures will be different.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is the ideal route to go.